# Glass tube diameter to hold water when turned upside down

Tags: forces, surface-tension

If I have a glass tube that is closed at one end and has length l, how can I find the range of diameters that the tube must be so that the water does not fall out of the tube when the tube is turned upside down?

I think I need to do a force or energy balance, but I could use some help in approaching this problem. I know at such a small scale, gravity will not be as impactful as say, the surface tension.

the length, l, of the tube should be included in the solution

Answer (score 6):

This is harder than it sounds.

There are three things to consider.

1. For a very narrow tube, for example $\lt 1~\rm{mm}$ diameter, the surface tension will be able to support a column of liquid - even if the other end of the tube is open. The pressure difference that can be sustained across a curved liquid surface with radius of curvature $R$ is calculated as the force on the circumference ($F = 2\pi R \gamma$) divided by the area $\pi R^2$, giving $\Delta p = \frac{2\gamma}{R}$. As the tube gets narrower, you will be able to sustain longer and longer columns of liquid.
2. If you have a slightly larger tube, atmospheric pressure will be the significant term (this requires the other end of the tube to be closed...). In principle, you can support a column of 10 m of water at normal atmospheric pressure; in practice, the saturated vapor pressure of liquid means that the pressure above the liquid will not be 0, and there will be some temperature dependent correction. I discussed this [in this earlier answer to a related question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/168038/26969).
3. There will come a size of tube where atmospheric pressure cannot hold the liquid in, because of instability of the liquid surface. The problem is that if the surface can distort, there will be parts at higher (internal) pressure than others. What this means is that when the tube gets large enough that surface tension no longer defines the shape of the surface, an air bubble will be able to "sneak past" the water surface, and liquid will pour out. This doesn't depend so much on the height of the liquid column, as on the diameter of the orifice.

I have never seen that calculated explicitly, but I believe the following argument should allow us to estimate the approximate diameter. We know the pressure difference across the surface due to surface tension scales with the inverse of the radius of curvature. If we assume, generously, that the surface curves "to the maximum", then when the differential gravitation-induced pressure becomes comparable to the surface-tension induced pressure difference, things become unstable. In other words,

$$\frac{2\gamma}{R}\approx \rho g R\\
R \approx \sqrt{\frac{2\gamma}{\rho g}}$$

Substituting typical values for water, we find that the critical diameter of a tube that won't hold water when turned upside down is

$$R\approx \sqrt{\frac{2\cdot 0.07}{1000\cdot 10}}\approx 3.7 mm$$

This suggests that a tube with a diameter greater than about 7 mm will no be able to "hold" a column of water when turned upside down, which is certainly on the right order of magnitude. Note that in the above simplified analysis I ignored the effect of "contact angle" which reduces the pressure differential for hydrophilic surfaces (since the radius of curvature would increase to greater than the radius of the orifice). I think that's outside the scope of the question...

Comment: Are you suggesting that there is not really a way to calculate the minimum diameter? Perhaps the minimum diameter is just an infinitesimally small number?

Comment: @JacksonHart  it depends on the surface tension and contact angle; but it usually doesn't have to be "infinitesimally small". I show above that 7 mm is too big, but experience tells me that 1 mm is definitely small enough.

Comment: Would it be too much for me to ask something? I think I have misunderstood the question but now have more information. Instead of looking at the range of diameters, it should have been the range as dictated by the length. Could you help to address this now with the new information? I am guessing we need to take more into consideration now

Comment: In other words, the length 'l' should be part of the answer

Comment: Did you see my addition to the problem?

Comment: My point (2) basically addresses that. Given a certain atmospheric pressure, you can support a column of water equivalent to that pressure. Or you can support a higher one if your tube diameter is very small, since the additional pressure is $\frac{2\gamma}{R}$. This results in $\rho g \ell =  \frac{2\gamma}{R}$ or $R = \frac{2\gamma}{\rho g \ell}$, ignoring atmospheric effects. This means you can support a 1 m column of water when the diameter of the tube is < 28 µm (again I am ignoring contact angle effects - this is "for illustration only")

Answer (score 1):

I am not exactly sure what you wish to show.

You can set up a water barometer in the same way as a [mercury barometer is set up](http://practicalphysics.org/simple-mercury-barometer.html).

As it will be about 10 metres high is has to be made of thick wall plastic/rubber tubing with the final metre or so a piece of thick walled glass tubing sealed at the end.  This is so you can see the water meniscus at the top of the column of water.
You need to remove as much dissolved air from the water otherwise the air will come out of solution and prevent the low pressure region at the top being produced.  One way of doing this is to boil the water and then allow it to cool in a completely full sealed bottle/container.

Comment: I am looking for a way to determine the Diameter of the tube as a function of l such that the water does not fall out of the glass tube when turned upside down

Comment: I understand and think that @Floris has some excellent pointers in the answer (s)he wrote.